# Solve this 2nd deriv algebraically? Or graph it?

Tags: calculus

Came across a problem I'm not sure how to approach.

Find the number of inflection points on $[0,3]$ for $y=x^2 - \sin(2x^2)$

It is easy to do this with a graphing calculator, but I wanted to do it via $y''$ ..

$y=x^2 - \sin(2x^2)$

$y'=2x-\cos(2x^2)(4x)$

$y''=2 - [(4x)(-\sin(2x^2)(4x)+\cos(2x^2)(4)]$

How would you solve $y''=0$ ?

Comment: are not the inflection points of $x^2 - \sin 2x^2$ and $x - \sin 2x$ related?

Comment: The Newton-Raphson method or the Secant Method are popular choices for finding roots.

Comment: Ok, is it safe to assume finding roots of that $y''$ is out of scope for an introductory Calculus course?  (Newton-Raphson / Secant Method)